# How do I customize Material UI in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am very new at using this UI framework along with React. I was allocated to develop an application which is supposed to have more design pattern and I chose a framework that also don't rely on Jquery code. However, I am struggling to customize pre-made components. They have a override section on their website but I didn't understand it very well.

I know that there are 2 ways of customizing an element

1. You can create a `const styles = theme => { styles here }`. Then you invoke a higher order component called withStyles. then the css properties defined will be available on `classes` prop.
2. You can also use classes property to change inner components, example: `<Drawer classes={x}>`.

the Second one is the one I don't understand exactly how it works. For instance they have a  component. But to change its background for me was very complicated, I had to change it manually on my custom .css file. I couldnt use className and even using classes property it didn't work.

Can anyone explain to me a little better how exactly the customization is done?

Answer (score 15):

The background, and other colors you can change by [updating the theme](https://material-ui.com/customization/themes/). That way you can customize primary/secondary background and text colors, as well as use that in your styles.

As for the custom styling of particular components; the idea is to use `withStyles` as a Higher Order Component, wrapping your components. It takes `theme` as the parameter and passes `classes` as props to wrapped component.

Example:

```
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles';

const styles = theme => ({
  someClass: {
    padding: theme.spacing.unit * 5
  },
  otherClass: {
    background: 'red'
  }
});
```

Once the styles are defined, you can use them in your component like so:

```
const MyComponent = (props) => {
  return (<Button className={props.classes.someClass}>Some Action</Button>)
}

export default withStyles(styles)(MyComponent);
```

The `withStyles` will pass the `styles` in the props as `classes`, and you can then use them. If you're using functional components, you can access them via `props.classes`, if you're extending `Component`, they will be in `this.props.classes`

If you wish to use multiple classes, you'll need to install `classnames` dependency, and import it:

```
import React from 'react';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles';
import classNames from 'classnames';


const styles = theme => ({
  someClass: {
    padding: theme.spacing.unit * 5
  },
  otherClass: {
    background: 'red'
  }
});

const MyComponent = (props) => {
  return (<Button className={classNames(props.classes.someClass, props.classes.otherClass)}>Some Action</Button>)
}

export default withStyles(styles)(MyComponent);
```

The `classes` property can also be used to set multiple classes, but that depends on the Material-UI component styling API. For example, for `Tab` component

```
<Tab label="Hello" classes={ { root: classes.tab, selected: classes.tabSelected }} />
```

takes `root` as styles to be applied by default, and `selected` will be applied when tab is selected. In this case, the `styles` would contain:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  tab: {
    minWidth: 'auto',
    fontSize: '11px',
    fontWeight: 'bold'
  },
  tabSelected: {
    background: theme.palette.background.paper,
    color: theme.palette.secondary.main
  },
};
```

Note that these are using the Tab's [CSS API](https://material-ui.com/api/tab/#css), to map custom styles with predefined class names.

And, of course, the Component with `Tab` would need to be wrapped in `withStyles(styles)(Component)`.

Here's a [live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/qvrxp8wxx4?module=%2Fsrc%2FNavigation.js) with customized theme, and customized buttons taking multiple classes.

Comment: How has this not been marked as the correct answer I'll never know! Thanks